# TypeScript: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript

```
interface SomeType {
  a: string;
  b?: string;
}

const foo: SomeType = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'there'
};

const bar: SomeType = {
  a: 'hello'
};
bar.b = 'there';

// Error on this line
const str: string = foo.b;

// These lines have no error
const str2: string = foo.b ? foo.b : '';
const str3: string = foo.b!;
const str4: string = bar.b;
```

In the example above, we have 2 flavors creating an object of `SomeType`, which has an optional property `b`. When declaring `foo`, we are setting the value of `b` when the object is created. For `bar`, we are setting a value of `b` after the object has been created.

When creating the first string, `str`, there is an error:

> **Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)**

This error is mitigated with the approaches for `str2` and `str3`. I understand that in these examples, we are either checking the value of `foo.b` or asserting that we know `foo.b` has a value.

I'm not understanding why the error does not appear when `str4` is created. Why is TypeScript able to detect that `bar.b` is **not** `undefined` but it wasn't able to detect the same thing for `foo.b`? What is it about the way we are setting the property that results in this error?

(TypeScript Version 3.8.2)

Comment: It looks like typescript can tell that bar.b is either a string or undefined,

Comment: Because `const` only applies to `foo` and not the properties of `foo`. `foo.b` Is not `const` so could be `undefined`. All the workaround are ensuring that if it is `undefined` a string is supplied (or it’s forced).

Comment: A shorthand for str2 is `foo.b ?? ''`. Not that it matters, but `foo.b === ''` is `false`, so you would be re-assigning it to another empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `SomeType` from the line `const foo: SomeType = ...` will make the code work.

```js
interface SomeType {
  a: string;
  b?: string;
}

const foo = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'there'
};

const bar: SomeType = {
  a: 'hello'
};
bar.b = 'there';

// No more error on this line
const str: string = foo.b;

// These lines have no error
const str2: string = foo.b ? foo.b : '';
const str3: string = foo.b!;
const str4: string = bar.b;
```

In the original code, you are casting object `{ a:..., b:...}` to an `interface`. In this case `SomeType`:

```js
const foo: SomeType = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'there'
};
```

Simplest example of this would be, if you modify last line for `str4` to add cast, you will produce same error:

```js
const str4: string = (bar as SomeType).b; // error, because of the cast
```

Comment: It makes sense for removing the error but I'm still not seeing why the compiler was not complaining about `bar.b`, which is also `SomeType`. If I were to remove `SomeType` from where `foo` is created, TypeScript will no longer enforce that `foo` matches that interface. If the interface described a `User` object with `firstName` and `lastName`, it's important that all objects implement the interface. Let's say I update to add an `address` property to the interface. `foo` would not get a compiler error but if I'm using it as a `User`, I would want the warning so I can update the code.

Comment: I assume that compiler does not trace assignment of nested values when type is declared. But I also did not suggest that you remove interface. Correct use of that interface would be that all code operating with `b` checks for `undefined`, exactly because you want it to work for all instances of the `interface`.

Comment: In other words. This is limitation of the compiler, but equally the way you use `b` is not best practice in general cases either.

Answer (score -1):

There are chances that you see this error in almost all of your components if you enable the `strictTemplates` in the `angularCompilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` file.

[image]

From Angular 9, we have this new feature called [strictTemplates](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#stricttemplates).

```
  "angularCompilerOptions":{
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
```

It is indeed a good feature, however, if you don't have enough time to fix all these errors, you can just set this to false, for example, when you have an important release.

There is a good [blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/angular-9s-best-hidden-feature-strict-template-checking/) that explains this more.